# A beautiful mathematical induction problem: $11 \mid 1+2^{2^n}+3^{2^n}+4^{2^n}+5^{2^n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

In a book on mathematical induction, I found the following problem:

Let $p$ be a prime number of the form $4k+3$. Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2 k+1} i^{2^{n}}$

is divisible by $p$.

So I applied this in the particular case where $11=4\cdot2+3$

Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N},$

$11 \mid 1+2^{2^n}+3^{2^n}+4^{2^n}+5^{2^n}.$

So, I wrote $P(k+1)$ as follows: $1+(2^{2^n})^2+(3^{2^n})^2+(4^{2^n})^2+(5^ {2^n})^2$

Now, I'm stuck, I can't apply my inductive hypothesis in such a way that proves $P(k+1)$. What do you think of this discussion?

Comment: We even have $11\mid 5^n+4^n+3^n+2^n+1$ for every even positive integer $n$ expcept the multiples of $10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the particular case $p=11$, define $P(n): 11 | 1+2^{2^n}+3^{2^n}+4^{2^n}+5^{2^n} $. $P(1)$ holds, and suppose $P(k)$ with $k>1$ holds too. Then we need to show $P(k+1) \implies 11 | 1+4^{2^k}+9^{2^k}+16^{2^k}+25^{2^k}$ holds. But in the ring of integers $Z_{11}$, $9 = -2$, $16=5$ and $25=3$, since the characteristic is $11$. Therefore, $P(k+1)$ is the same thing as saying $11| 1 + 4^{2^k}+(-2)^{2^k}+5^{2^k}+3^{2^k}$, which is very certainly true by our inductive hypothesis $P(k)$.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. It was good for me to have taken algebra II the previous semester. In fact, I understood your solution better due to congruences.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, my solution essentially uses congruence, ie the idea that when considering $Z_{11}$, it is the same idea to think of $k$ and $11+k$.

Comment: i.e. $\bmod 11\!:\ S\equiv \{1, 4, 9, 5, 3\}\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{S^2}\equiv \{1,5,4,3,9\}\equiv \color{#c00}S.\,$ For $n=1$ we have $\,f_1 \equiv \sum S\equiv 0,\,$ next $\,f_2\equiv \sum \color{#c00}{S^2}\equiv \sum \color{#c00}S\equiv f_1\equiv 0\,$ is how the inductive step works @BENNAM